# BeautifulSoup doesn't return the tag it supposed to(empty result)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data from the website using Beautifulsoup Python, but it doesn't return the value it supposed to return.
Following is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://finance.naver.com/item/sise.nhn?code=005930'

# send a HTTP request to the URL of the webpage I want to access
r = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

# making the soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('iframe', attrs={'title': '일별 시세'}))
```

---

And it returns,

```
<iframe bottommargin="0" frameborder="0" height="360" marginheight="0" name="day" scrolling="no" src="/item/sise_day.nhn?code=005930" title="일별 시세" topmargin="0" width="100%"></iframe>
```

There is no HTML tags contained in the printed result. However, if i look at the developer tool on the webpage, it clearly shows there are a lot of tags inside **'iframe'** tag.[image]

[image]

So my question is, **why doesn't my code return the all the tags inside
'iframe' tag that I see from the developer tool on the webpage?**

I've tried look up some information, but none of it gave me clear answers.
Is it because it's loaded by javascript? if it is how can I check my webpage
that I'm trying to scrape is loaded by javascript?

And lastly, what module/library should I use to scrape the data I want if it is
loaded by javascript?

Comment: Isn't it because you want the data in the html table rather than the heading?

Comment: @RichardKYu I don't understand the question. What do you exactly mean?

Comment: For instance, if you run: 

```td = soup.findAll('td', attrs = {'class':'num'})```
Then
```print(td)```
You should see the numbers such as 50,300 within some of the output

Comment: @RichardKYu I still don't think I understand you. For example, the number I'm trying to scrape is in the **'span'** tag, with the class **'tah p11'**. Although I tried `soup.find_all('span', class_="tah p11"))`, still doesn't give me the value I want.

Answer (score 5):

The table is available inside an iframe.You need send request for that iframe url.
You can use pandas to read_html() and get the table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://finance.naver.com/item/sise.nhn?code=005930'

# send a HTTP request to the URL of the webpage I want to access
r = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

# making the soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

newurl="https://finance.naver.com" +soup.find('iframe', attrs={'title': '일별 시세'})['src']
dfs=pd.read_html(newurl)
df=dfs[0]
df = df.dropna(how='any',axis=0)
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
            날짜       종가     전일비       시가       고가       저가         거래량
1   2019.11.29  50300.0  1000.0  51200.0  51400.0  50200.0  11012292.0
2   2019.11.28  51300.0   900.0  51900.0  52100.0  51300.0   6833885.0
3   2019.11.27  52200.0   400.0  51800.0  52300.0  51600.0   7546261.0
4   2019.11.26  51800.0     0.0  51900.0  52900.0  51800.0  27372226.0
5   2019.11.25  51800.0   200.0  52200.0  52600.0  51700.0   9050625.0
9   2019.11.22  51600.0   600.0  51000.0  51600.0  50900.0   8478310.0
10  2019.11.21  51000.0  1000.0  51600.0  52100.0  50600.0  14298646.0
11  2019.11.20  52000.0  1500.0  53400.0  53400.0  52000.0  12560070.0
12  2019.11.19  53500.0     0.0  53200.0  53500.0  52700.0   8907177.0
13  2019.11.18  53500.0   200.0  53600.0  53800.0  53200.0   7746554.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It actually works. But I have a question. why do i have to send request for the iframe? And the table actually has multiple pages. from first page to 590. How do I collect all these data? Currently I can only scrape what you just answered me. I see your code '`[src]`' at the end of `newurl`, do I have to change that? but even if I click on the second or third page, the iframe src doesn't change in the webpage that I'm trying to scrape.